# How to create an array of sub-forms with CForm?

Tags: yii

I have an array of models, all of them being instances of one class. I need to create a form which contains subforms corresponding to the models from the array.

Have to use CForm, because i've made a nice small extension of it, which can render subforms in CJuiTabs. In the code used at the moment POST-parameter names are wrong, because they get prefixed by the name of the class of a model from the array.

Below you can see a snippet of HTML-code generated. See those YPageInfo[...] named inputs? That's the problem - only one set of inputs with this prefix gets received by the server.

```
<div style="visibility:hidden"><input type="hidden" value="1" name="yform_20bd4d2c" id="yform_20bd4d2c" /></div>
<div class="row field_name">
<label for="YPageRevision_name">Name</label>
<input name="YPageRevision[name]" id="YPageRevision_name" type="text" maxlength="45" />

</div>
<div class="row field_parent_id">
<label for="YPageRevision_parent_id">Parent Id</label>
<input id="YPageRevision_parent_id_hidden" name="YPageRevision[parent_id]" type="hidden" /><input id="YPageRevision_parent_id" type="text" value="" name="autocomplete-field" />

</div>
<div id="yw1">
<ul>
<li><a href="#enSubFormTab" title="enSubFormTab">en</a></li>
<li><a href="#ruSubFormTab" title="ruSubFormTab">ru</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="enSubFormTab"><div class="row field_title">
<label for="YPageInfo_title" class="required">Title <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input name="YPageInfo[title]" id="YPageInfo_title" type="text" maxlength="256" />

</div>
<div class="row field_content">
<label for="YPageInfo_content" class="required">Content <span class="required">*</span></label>
<textarea name="YPageInfo[content]" id="YPageInfo_content"></textarea>

</div>


</div>
<div id="ruSubFormTab"><div class="row field_title">
<label for="YPageInfo_title" class="required">Title <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input name="YPageInfo[title]" id="YPageInfo_title" type="text" maxlength="256" />

</div>
<div class="row field_content">
<label for="YPageInfo_content" class="required">Content <span class="required">*</span></label>
<textarea name="YPageInfo[content]" id="YPageInfo_content"></textarea>

</div>


</div>
</div>

<div class="row buttons"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Create" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to do what I needed.

In the `elements` property of the sub-form there are some inputs declared. Each standard input element declared there is an instance of `CFormInputElement`, so it has the `attributes` property. Here you can set any HTML attribute, which will be rendered in the resulting input tag. I put my custom `name` attribute here, and change it in a loop, where i create sub-forms configuration items for the main CForm.

Maybe there is a better way?